# Codeigniter .htaccess redirect url issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter-3

I want redirect my old url to new url the redirection is working fine but there is an issue in url, the redirected url is not in proper way

**For Example :**

Old url :www.example.com/pages/product_popup/1

New url : www.example.com/product-syrup

But it is redirecting in this way

Redirected url : www.example.com/product-syrup/?/pages/product_popup/1

**My htaccess:**

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]


Redirect 301 /pages/product_popup/1 /product-syrup/



## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

How can i overcome this? Am using GoDaddy hosting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `RewriteEngine On` in new line add this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/product_popup/1$ /product-syrup [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

In codeigniter you can do this by URI Routing

Under application / config / routes.php

```
$route['pages/product_popup/(:any)'] = 'product-syrup';
```

A URL containing the word “pages/product_popup/(:any)” will be remapped to the “product-syrup” class.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html